# Create subpage /user/ or /my-profile/ like /author/ with additional query like /user/user123

Tags: customization, pages, query, urls

I am creating some project and because of task, I need this:

domain.com/user/user123 - *return profile of "user123" with his personal info*

domain.com/my-profile - *return profile of current logged user*

I've tried **add_query_args** or some tutorials ( likehttp://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/), but it doesn't work for me.

Maybe there is an option with htaccess way, but this part is very confusing me (I mean when I use WordPress way). Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you can do that with `add_rewrite_rule();` function to map the url to specific query variables.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

```
function myfunc_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule('user/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=user&username=$matches[1]', 'top');
 }

 function myfunc_username_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'username';
  return $vars;
 }

add_action('init', 'myfunc_rewrite_rules');
 //add query vars (username) to wordpress
 add_filter('query_vars', 'myfunc_username_query_vars');

function myfunc_display() {
  $userpage = get_query_var('pagename');
  $username = get_query_var('username');
  if ('user' == $userpage && '' == $username ):
   //show all users
   exit;
  elseif ('user' == $userpage && '' != $username ):
   //show specific user
   exit;
  endif;
 }

 //register plugin custom pages display
 add_filter('template_redirect', 'myfunc_display');
```

This tutorial can help: http://clivern.com/how-to-add-custom-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress/

**UPDATE:**

After you run this code, you must go to `Settings->Permalinks` and just hit save button to flush all rewrite rules.(This is the solution for many permalink issues)

Comment: So, part that shows all users working well, thank you. But I don't know why, WordPress redirect me to main page when I add **user123** after /user/

Comment: But this work correctly - domain.com/?pagename=user&username=a and of course this - domain.com/user/?username=a

Comment: @Doctore Try flushing rewrite rules by going to Settings->Permalinks and just hit save. then try again

Comment: @Doctore You're welcome my friend