# Need help adding rewrite rules to page

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a url structure like this where taobao is a page:

```
http://website.com/taobao/?item=123123
```

I need to change it to like this

```
http://website.com/taobao/item/123123
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
 add_rewrite_rule( 'product/([^/]+)', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can follow below step :

```
1) Login to wp-admin

2) Goto the setting in sidebar menu Into permalinks

3) "Common Settings" In select the Post name and "Product Permalinks" automatically set like /product/sample-product/
```

I hope it's useful.

[image]

Comment: taobao is page name . full url is `http://mywebsite.com/taobao/product=11212132` and we don`t want to change any woocommerce default permalinks

Comment: Common Settings in permalinks use can set in post name or not?

Comment: I am update my ans. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have a mistake in your URL. it must be `/taobao/?product=11212132` (pay attention to the question mark)

I have answered this question here: [Create subpage /user/ or /my-profile/ like /author/ with additional query like /user/user123](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258923/create-subpage-user-or-my-profile-like-author-with-additional-query-like/258930#258930)

Comment: added this `add_rewrite_rule('taobao/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', 'top');` but still dont work. I want to redirect `http://website.com/taobao/?item=123123`  to `http://website.com/taobao/item/123123`

Comment: @RohitKishore You must replace `product=` with `item=`